# How to restore: Database intact but folders deleted

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting

I never thought I'd come to having to ask this question -- one trusts web hosting companies to keep our data intact, but somehow they have deleted my entire Wordpress installation while leaving the database intact. I've also lost the backups as they were on the web server. How can I restore the wordpress installation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that you have now learned the hard way that you should ***not***:

- trust only your web hosting company to keep your data intact, or
- keep your backups on your web server.

Sadly, restoring your WordPress installation -- if at all possible -- will most likely not be easy!

- You *might* be able to retrieve the image files that were stored in those directories from the cached versions of the individual pages/posts inside Google's cache.
- In the unlikely event that your site was implemented solely via unmodified theme/plugins, then remembering which ones they were and reinstalling them will restore much of the directory contents. However, any customizations made to the PHP files are almost surely lost.

Comment: Sadly I thought this would be the answer. Thanks for delivering the bad news gently :)